# Mosh over Tor, instead of SSH over Tor?

Tags: tor, mosh

#### Benefit that I'm looking for:

- Tor is slow. When SSH'ing over Tor doing even the basic things takes a lot of time and concentration
- Especially painful are: editing a file or a mistyped command line because when finding the spot to edit you can't use the keyboard repeat functions and end up counting how many places to shift
- Mosh solves this problem by editing text on the client side cache and reconciling with the server in the background

#### The issue is:

- Tor does not support UDP
- Mosh does not support TCP

I could not find a guide. [This one](https://matt.traudt.xyz/posts/mosh-over-tor-RczgjEqF.html) came close yet it runs some communication over the regular Internet which kills the privacy that Tor offers.

Comment: It seems like you did your research! That’s awesome. However, I wonder how you arrive at this conclusion: “Seems like it should be easy to tunnel mosh traffic over Tor.” — because from what I can see it’s actually the opposite. It can never work. By tunneling Mosh over TCP you’d throw away all the benefits it offers.

Comment: By tunneling over TCP/SSH I'd still have the client side text editing that I'm describing. I'm ok with throwing away mosh's roaming benefit.

Comment: I'm actually not sure whether Mosh's SSP protocol would sensibly work over TCP, either. It would make more sense to take _just_ the local editing part (which has nothing to do with Mosh in itself) and implement it at terminal emulator level.

Comment: Yea, I'm interested to in the Mosh client's "Instant local echo and line editing" https://mosh.org/ - is there is a way to tunnel / VPN the client-server traffic for SSP without modifying mosh?

Comment: Any updates here? Still not possible? @AleksandrLevchuk